# Pass functions as parameters in interface method definition

Tags: c#, interface, .net-3.5, parameters, lambda

I am currently attempting to work with lambdas using (possibly) C#'s Func or Action types.

I would like to create an interface called IMyInterface that defines a method called CreateCRUD.  This should take 5 parameters.  The first is a string.  The next four are functions that call create, read, update and delete methods.

```
interface IMyInterface
{
    void CreateCRUD(string name, Action<void> createFunc, Action<void> readFunc, Action<void> updateFunc, Action<void> deleteFunc);
}
```

The four function definitions should take no parameters and return nothing.  The code above does not compile.  Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the non-generic [`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx) instead.

```
interface IMyInterface
{
    void CreateCRUD(string name, Action createFunc, Action readFunc, Action updateFunc, Action deleteFunc);
}
```

Comment: "void is not a type": that's not strictly true... `typeof(void)` returns `System.Void`. But it can't be used as a generic type parameter

Comment: Huh.  Didn't know that.  Edited my answer and learned something new today.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

[`Action<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx):

> Encapsulates a method that has a single parameter and does not return
>   a value.

So, you are trying to force delegate with one parameter of type `void`.

All you need to do is to use `Action` without type:

```
interface IMyInterface
{
    void CreateCRUD(string name, Action createFunc, Action readFunc, Action updateFunc, Action deleteFunc);
}
```

If you want to force parameter types in your delegates then you can should use `Action<T>` e.g. `Action<int>`, which *means* method with `int` parameter.

Comment: So, the only difference between Func and Action is the return type?  Action doesn't have one, Func does?

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
Public delegate Action<T> MyActionDelegate;

interface IMyInterface 
{     
void CreateCRUD(string name, MyActionDelegate createFunc, MyActionDelegate readFunc, MyActionDelegate updateFunc, MyActionDelegate deleteFunc); 
}
```

Comment: Question: How does creating a delegate differ from the answers below?

Comment: It doesn't. However if there wasn't a suitable delegate defined already, you'd define one and then you could use it as a type in the method.

Comment: Would it be proper to create 4 delegates, one for each of the CRUD operations?

Comment: This won't even compile.  `T` doesn't exist in context here.

Comment: @Servy Which bit some teh phrase "Something like" caused you a horrendous comprehension difficulty?

Comment: @Norla. Only if they had four different signatures. Byh doing this all you are saying is when somethinbg calls something that implements CreateCRUD is will pass in 4 methods with no parameters, that return an Action something or other.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Because I don't really see where you're going with this.  What should the user use for `T`?  Do you realize that by doing that the parameters are actually methods that return methods that return a value, not just methods that return a value?  Did you pick up on the fact that the methods don't actually need to return any value at all, they should be void returning?  Did you realize that there is almost never a need to define a delegate anymore, your delegate is essentially the same as just using `Func<Action<T>>`?

Comment: The main point of my answer was to illustrate that delegate was the answer, not to simply provide an existing delegate, and explain nothing. If the guy knew all the stuff you seem to be assuming I don't, wouldn't be here asking questions of this quality would he?